How do I find the total music played on each day of the week in pandas?
I am to apply consecutive filtering and logical indexing to the pandas df to display the number of plays each day for the week for two cities as you can see below.
# importing pandas
import pandas as pd

# reading the file and storing it to df
df = pd.read_csv('/datasets/music_project_en.csv')

# renaming columns
df = df.rename(columns={
    '  userID': 'user_id',
    'Track': 'track',
    '  City  ': 'city',
    'Day': 'day'
})

# looping over column names and replacing missing values with 'unknown'
columns_to_replace = ['track', 'artist', 'genre']

for column in columns_to_replace:
    df[column] = df[column].fillna('unknown')

# removing obvious duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# function for replacing implicit duplicates
def replace_wrong_genres(wrong_genres, correct_genre):
    for wrong_genre in wrong_genres:
        df['genre'] = df['genre'].replace(wrong_genre, correct_genre)
        
# removing implicit duplicates
replace_wrong_genres(['hip', 'hop', 'hip-hop'], 'hiphop')


# <creating the function number_tracks()>

            
print(number_tracks(Monday, Springfield))
# We'll declare a function with two parameters: day=, city=.
# Let the track_list variable store the df rows where
# the value in the 'day' column is equal to the day= parameter and, at the same time, 
# the value in the 'city' column is equal to the city= parameter (apply consecutive filtering 
# with logical indexing).

# Let the track_list_count variable store the number of 'user_id' column values in track_list
# (found with the count() method).

# Let the function return a number: the value of track_list_count.

# The function counts tracked played for a certain city and day.
# It first retrieves the rows with the intended day from the table,
# then filters out the rows with the intended city from the result,
# then finds the number of 'user_id' values in the filtered table,
# then returns that number.

# To test and see what it returns, wrap test function calls in print(),
# but don't leave any test behind, otherwise your result will not validate correctly.




# 1. the number of songs played in Springfield on Monday
print("1: " + str(your code here))
# 2. the number of songs played in Shelbyville on Monday
print("2: " + str(your code here))
# 3. the number of songs played in Springfield on Wednesday
print("3: " + str(your code here))
# 4. the number of songs played in Shelbyville on Wednesday
print("4: " + str(your code here))
# 5. the number of songs played in Springfield on Friday
print("5: " + str(your code here))
# 6. the number of songs played in Shelbyville on Friday
print("6: " + str(your code here))

I am required to create a function and use for loop with if statements then display the work, I tried the below code under the comment that says # <creating the function number_tracks()>
def number_tracks(day, city): 
    track_list_count = 0
    for track_list in df:
        if day == track_list['day'] and city == track_list['city']
            print('some')
        
print(number_tracks(Monday, Springfield))


Use a groupby for this. df.groupby(['day', 'city'])['track'].count()

This might help optimize your code.
#fill multiple columns at once
df[['track', 'artist', 'genre']] = df[['track', 'artist', 'genre']].fillna('unknown')

df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

#replace multiple values at once
df['genre'] = df['genre'].replace(['hip', 'hop', 'hip-hop'], 'hiphop')

#function
def number_tracks(day, city):
    track_list = df[(df['day']==day) & (df['city']==city)]
    track_list_count = track_list['user_id'].count()
    return track_list_count

#first question
print("1: " + str(number_tracks('Springfield', 'Monday'))


This works, thank you so much. how can i create a table using pd.Dataframe with previous results?

Great! @ifly6's comment above would give you a dataframe with every possible combination

Yes, So i have the columns as ['city', ' Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday'] but the data parameter to pass in the Dataframe() method should be the results i got from the numbers_tracks function

The most efficient way to do this would be without the function using df.groupby(['city', 'day'])['track'].count().unstack(). It's definitely doable using the function but it would help to see the prompt. Can you create a new post with all the details?

Use pd.DataFrame to create a table, where
 Column names are: ```['city', 'monday', 'wednesday', 'friday']```.
 The data is the results you got from ```number_tracks()```


i manually entered the results from the function and it world info = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Springfield', 15740, 11056, 15945], ['Shelbyville', 5614, 7003, 5895]], columns=['city', 'monday', 'wednesday', 'friday']) can we connect outside stackoverflow, i would like to learn more and could use your help and direction please.

While I appreciate your enthusiasm, I must insist. Creating a new post with your question here on StackOverflow allows other people to learn as well, and you can get valuable input from multiple experts.

ok will do just that

what is the outcome when you tried to run the function? please provide further details on what happened when you tried the code itself.
but, assuming you tried to run the number_tracks() and the method in it doesn't show any desired outcome. try this inside your function.
def number_tracks(day, city):
    track_list = df[(df['day'] == day) & (df['city'] == city)]
    track_list_count = track_list['user_id'].count()
    
    return track_list_count

or, you could do this to check the value while iterates over each row in the DataFrame using df.iterrows().
def number_tracks(day, city):
    track_list_count = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['day'] == day and row['city'].strip() == city:
            track_list_count += 1
    return track_list_count

